# Multivariate Time Series Forecasting: Error normalizing testing set

Tags: python, lstm, normalization, scaling

I've never tried LSTM before. I have 3 datasets: train.csv, test.csv and weather.csv

train.csv has the following variables:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1400 entries, 0 to 1399
Data columns (total 29 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------        --------------  -----  
 0   date          1400 non-null   object 
 1   MELLEGUE      1400 non-null   float64
 2   BEN METIR     1400 non-null   float64
 3   KASSEB        1400 non-null   float64
 4   BARBARA       1400 non-null   float64
 5   SIDI SALEM    1400 non-null   float64
 6   BOU-HEURTMA   1400 non-null   float64
 7   JOUMINE       1400 non-null   float64
 8   GHEZALA       1400 non-null   float64
 9   SEJNANE       1400 non-null   float64
 10  S. EL BARRAK  1400 non-null   float64
 11  SILIANA       1400 non-null   float64
 12  LAKHMESS      1400 non-null   float64
 13  RMIL          1400 non-null   float64
 14  BIR M'CHERGA  1400 non-null   float64
 15  RMEL          1400 non-null   float64
 16  NEBHANA       1400 non-null   float64
 17  SIDI SAAD     1400 non-null   float64
 18  EL HAOUAREB   1400 non-null   float64
 19  SIDI AÏCH     1400 non-null   float64
 20  EL BREK       1400 non-null   float64
 21  BEZIRK        1400 non-null   float64
 22  CHIBA         1400 non-null   float64
 23  MASRI         1400 non-null   float64
 24  LEBNA         1400 non-null   float64
 25  HMA           1396 non-null   float64
 26  ABID          1396 non-null   float64
 27  Zarga         645 non-null    float64
 28  Ziatine       645 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(28), object(1)
```

test.csv:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 366 entries, 0 to 365
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   date    366 non-null    object
dtypes: object(1)
```

weather.csv:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1978 entries, 0 to 1977
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   date    1978 non-null   object 
 1   tavg    1978 non-null   float64
 2   tmin    1884 non-null   float64
 3   tmax    1915 non-null   float64
 4   prcp    1824 non-null   float64
 5   snow    0 non-null      float64
 6   wdir    1397 non-null   float64
 7   wspd    1663 non-null   float64
 8   wpgt    0 non-null      float64
 9   pres    1018 non-null   float64
 10  tsun    0 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(10), object(1)
```

The goal is to combine train.csv and weather.csv to train an LSTM model and forecast the features in the train.csv for the dates in the test.csv

Here's what I've done

```
# Load the datasets
train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
weather_df = pd.read_csv("weather.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

# Merge the datasets
merged_df = pd.merge(train_df, weather_df, on="date")
merged_test_df = pd.merge(test_df, weather_df, on="date")

# Split the merged_df into train and test datasets
train_df = merged_df[merged_df["date"] < "2019-02-06"]
test_df = merged_test_df

# Normalize the data using MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_train_df = scaler.fit_transform(train_df.iloc[:, 1:])
scaled_test_df = scaler.transform(test_df.iloc[:, 1:])

# Define the window size for the LSTM model
window_size = 30

# Create the training dataset
train_X, train_y = [], []
for i in range(window_size, scaled_train_df.shape[0]):
    train_X.append(scaled_train_df[i-window_size:i])
    train_y.append(scaled_train_df[i, :])
train_X, train_y = np.array(train_X), np.array(train_y)

# Build the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(train_y.shape[1]))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Train the model
model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=32)

# Make predictions on the test dataset using the trained LSTM model
test_X = []
for i in range(window_size, scaled_test_df.shape[0]):
    test_X.append(scaled_test_df[i-window_size:i])
test_X = np.array(test_X)
y_pred = model.predict(test_X)

# Save the predictions to a CSV file
pred_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=train_df.columns[1:])
pred_df.insert(0, "date", test_df["date"][window_size:].reset_index(drop=True))
pred_df.to_csv("predictions.csv", index=False)
```

However I'm getting an error here:

```
# Normalize the data using MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_train_df = scaler.fit_transform(train_df.iloc[:, 1:])
scaled_test_df = scaler.transform(test_df.iloc[:, 1:])

ValueError: X has 10 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 38 features as input.
```

Not sure what's happening. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: What's the value of `train_df.shape` and `test_df.shape`?

Comment: @NickODell train_df has 1400 rows and 29 columns while test_df has 366 rows and a single column which the date column containing dates to be used for testing (forecasting)

Comment: If you do `scaler.fit_transform(train_df.iloc[:, 1:])` followed by `scaler.transform(test_df.iloc[:, 1:])`, doesn't that require train_df and test_df to have the same number of columns, since MaxMinScaler is fitting per-column minimums and maximums?